# How to convert [ ][2]string to map[string] string in go?

Tags: arrays, string, go

I am retrieving an object called [`DockerInfo`](https://godoc.org/github.com/fsouza/go-dockerclient#DockerInfo) which has a field inside it called `SystemStatus` which is `[][2]string`, then in order to access the elements inside `SystemStatus` I am doing this, for example if the 4th element in `SystemStatus` is `["Nodes","6"]` then to access the number `6`

```
dockerinfo.SystemStatus[3][1]
```

But the `Nodes` elements are not fixed in 4th position always so I can not use indexing and instead I want to find number of nodes by for example writing

```
dockerinfo.SystemStatus["Nodes"]
```

How can I do that? Or how to transform the `SystemStatus` to `map[string]string` format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a simple `for` loop to iterate over the values of the `dockerinfo.SystemStatus` slice, and compare the first value to `"Nodes"`:

```
for _, v := range dockerinfo.SystemStatus {
    if v[0] == "Nodes" {
        // Got it!
        value := v[1] // This will be "6" in your example
        fmt.Println("Nodes value:", value)
        break
    }
}
```

This `value` will be of type `string` but it looks it holds a numerical data. If you want it as an `int` for example, you may use [`strconv.Atoi()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Atoi) to parse the number:

```
value := v[1]
if n, err := strconv.Atoi(value); err == nil {
    // n is of type int, use it like so
} else {
    // Not a number!
}
```

If you have to lookup values many times, it may be profitable to build a map from it. This is how you could do it:

```
ssmap := map[string]string{}
for _, v := range dockerinfo.SystemStatus {
    ssmap[v[0]] = v[1]
}

// And then you can do simple lookup:
if nodes, ok := ssmap["Nodes"]; ok {
    fmt.Println("Nodes value:", nodes)
} else {
    // Nodes not found!
}
```

Comment: thank you but I need to access other than Nodes element so how can I map them in a map for example I need to access Nodes,Status ,Containers ...

Comment: @saidsaifi Please see edited answer, conversion to map has been included.

Comment: Thankyou I upvoted and accepted your answer but I still did not reach 15 reputations

Comment: how can i get status of each node and all of them are elements of systemstatus for example SystemStatus{["Nodes","2"],["Node1","10.0.1.1"],["Status","Healthy"],["Node2","10.0.1.2" ],["Status","Pending"]}... there are 9 attributes for each Node and they all are under SystemStatus I could access it by indexing but i should find another way

Comment: @saidsaifi In this case I recommend you the first solution using a `for` loop. Once you find the node your looking for, subsequent elements will be what you're looking for. Modify the loop to also return the index for you to use, e.g. `for i, v := range dockerinfo.SystemStatus {}`